# C# Looping through an IEnumerable for a calculation that uses the n previous and n following elements

Tags: c#, list, foreach, ienumerable

I find myself frequently dealing with an IEnumerable object that I need to loop through an do a calculation for each element that depends on the n immediately prior and following objects.

One common example is calculating a rolling average, but other times the calculation is more complex than that and relies on several fields from each of the elements of the list

I am never sure about the best way to structure my loops. Efficiency matters, but maintainability and readability is more important.

- Sometimes I convert to a List and then use a for loop to get elements [i-1],[i],[i+1] and then perform my calculation.
- Other times I keep it as an IEnumerable, but I "cache" the previous couple of elements, so that I don't do the calculation for i until I have gotten to [i+1] in the foreach loop.
- I also considered using a linked list, so that I could use the .Previous and .Next methods.

Any suggestions on which technique would be the best to use?

Comment: Not going to opine right now (too many pros and cons for a short answer, and I don't have time for a long answer), but another possibility for some cases is two indicies you move in tandem. `i` starts at e.g. 0 and `j` at 3, you do stuff with `k` going from `i` to `j` (half-open, so hitting 0, 1 & 2), then you move `++i;++j;` and loop `k` again, until `++j > list.Count` (so j points just outside the list on the last pass).

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to make an extension method that provided a rolling "window" you could use.  This would allow you to write your loop in a simple way:

```
IEnumerable<IList<T>> CreateRollingWindow(IEnumerable<T> items, int size)
{
    LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();

    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        list.AddLast(item);
        if (list.Count == size)
        {
            yield return list.ToList();
            list.RemoveFirst();
        }
    }
}
```

This would then let you write your algorithms simply as:

```
foreach(var window as collection.CreateRollingWindow(5))
{
    double rollingAverage = window.Average(); // window is IList<T> here
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity - why the downvoting?

Comment: Probably someone who didn't understand your answer... Anyway, I like the fact that it's generic and reusable for different scenarios, but I wonder if there's a way to make it more efficient... If you can assume that the yielded list will be consumed before the next iteration, you can probably return it directly, which would avoid copying the data to a new list.

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Yes.  I purposely used `LinkedList<T>` instead of `Queue<T>` for the ToList() call - but that allows it to be more generic and safe, as you can use it in deferred execution scenarios, PLINQ, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
public static IEnumerable<double> RollingAverage(this IEnumerable<double> values, int count)
{
    var queue = new Queue<double>();
    foreach (var v in values)
    {
        queue.Enqueue(v);
        if (queue.Count == count)
        {
            yield return queue.Average();
            queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

It could probably be improved, but it seems to work...

EDIT: here's a slightly better version (it doesn't need to enumerate the queue to compute the average):

```
public static IEnumerable<double> RollingAverage(this IEnumerable<double> values, int count)
{
    var queue = new Queue<double>();
    double sum = 0.0;
    foreach (var v in values)
    {
        sum += v;
        queue.Enqueue(v);
        if (queue.Count == count)
        {
            yield return sum / count;
            sum -= queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```